# CSS selector by color regardless of representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select all elements on my page with a certain color, let's say red.
I know I can do it like this: `$("div[style=color:rgb(255,0,0)]")`. However, my problem is that there are different representations of the color red, e.g. `#FF0000` and simply `red`. But also any number of white spaces in `rgb(255, 0, 0)` still defines the color red.

I need to do it in a general way which would work for any color and will accept any representation of that color. Is there a way to define such a "smart" CSS selector?

Comment: `getComputedStyle` returns parsed rgba colors

Comment: Can I use this in a CSS selector though? It's part of a bigger selection filter...

Comment: You can't use it in a standard CSS selector, but since you're using jQuery, you can write a custom selector that makes use of getComputedStyle.

Comment: Try defining the css selector as a regex string. I'm not great at regex but it could start with something like `regex = "style=color:"` But as for what comes after the colon depends on what you want to select. If you want to select all possible formats, I would still say that there are a limited amount of possible formats so it wouldn't be too hard to make a short list.

Comment: getComputedStyle won't fit in a selector, but, in addition to dina's idea, you could _set_ the parsed value to the _.style._ again, homogenizing all the colors so that a CSS query _would_ work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. You want to filter only when the color is 'red' (literally, #FF00000)? Or also kind of for example 'darkred' will be included in your filter?

In the first case I don't really see a problem and a solution of kukkuz could work with some improvements.

According to what I know you cannot do that with CSS selectors

Comment: I don't care about the tone of the color. I can assume it's exact. What I need is to be agnostic to representation - to have a selector which works on the semantic level and doesn't just compare strings. And 'color' is also just an example. It could also be background-color or any other property of colors.

Comment: _“What I need is to be agnostic to representation - to have a selector which works on the semantic level”_ – haha, you’re funny. Color _is_ presentation. If you want semantic, then you would not be trying to select “by color” in the first place, but it would be the other way around: Elements would have a specific color only _because_ of their _semantic_ classification, not because it is randomly assigned via style attribute. And then selecting the right elements based on their semantics would be no problem either.

Comment: @CBroe `representing` does not mean `presenting` twice (not even once), it means a way of expressing a concept by some character or term. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/represent. And `semantics` is the meaning of the terms or characters (the concept behind each representation). http://www.dictionary.com/browse/semantics. So Dina's sentence actually makes lots of sense. Detecting the `red color` without taking into account the various ways to represent it IS doing it on a semantic level.

Comment: @Marc that was not my point. If you had a code base that emphasizes semantics, then colors would not be applied arbitrarily by placing style attributes on elements - but via CSS selectors from the stylesheet. And then those same selectors could be used to select the relevant elements, instead of trying to match actual color values.

Comment: @CBroe yes, but that is YOUR point, not the question here. What if you can't control how the page is built? the question is how to select all objects with a `red` color (any representation of it) in the `color attribute`. Anything else is simply not answering the question. And laughing at the OP to end up not answering the question is just bullying.

Comment: Sorry, didn’t want to bully anyone. But asking for _“a selector which works on the semantic level”_ just makes no sense IMHO when the site in question does _not_ use semantic coding. Assuming the HTML (resp. logic how colors are applied to elements) can not be changed, then there likely is no good answer here. If formats like `rgb()`, `rgba()` and `red` need to be matched - then one could simply write a matching attribute selector for each one individually. But if you then also demand different notations like `rgb(255, 0, 0)` with extra whitespace to be taken into consideration [...]

Comment: [...] then I am saying something somewhere is wrong in the system you are using. If you need users/admins(?) to be able to add arbitrary color values, then at least those should be “sanitized” into a consistent format at that point.

Answer (score 0):

By using this type of selector you are telling jquery to search for a string/sub string that contains the word that you are looking for.
But the options are endless.

Because you are searching for a string you have to consider all possibilities, including white spaces, different character sizes, more style attributes other then color that can contain number like 0 or 255 or ff or 00 etc...

This is not possible with the current support of selectors...

But if you will use jquery to get all elements and then check their color/background-color, you will get a true color representation.

it doesn't matter how the style is written, the browser will return back a color(it can be in hex or rgb depending on the browser).

I think that this behivor derives from the w3c rules...

a non elegent soulation would look like this:

```
$('div').each(function(){
if($(this).css('color') == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" || $(this).css('color') == "#FF0000"){
    $(this).css("color","green");
}
if($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" || $(this).css('background-color') == "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)"){
    $(this).css("background-color","green");
}});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zdu1adr7/4/

This one works on chrome,firefox,edge,ie 11/10/9.